# getColor()はContextCompatで未定義です

Tags: android, eclipse

getColorを使用したく、API23以降はContextCompat.getColor()でできるところまではわかりました。
しかし、実際に書いてみると「getColor()はContextCompatで未定義です」と言われてエラーになります。ライブラリはandroid.support.v4.context.ContextCompatをインポートしています。
他に問題はあるのでしょうか。

Eclipseで開発しています。初心者なので調べてはいますが、解決しないのでよろしくお願いします。

Comment: supportライブラリのバージョンはいくつでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。support libraryのバージョンはわからないのですが、ContextCompat.classというファイルを見ると、2つしかメソッドが定義されていませんでした。startActivities()というものが二つでした。
SDKManagerでリストが出てこない症状もあり、どうしたら最新のバージョンに更新できますか。android6.0やbuild toolsなどは自力で落としてきてやっています。

Comment: gContextCompatはandroid.support.v4. **content** のパッケージに含まれているようですが、質問のandroid.support.v4. **context** はおそらく誤記かと思います。クラスはロードできていそうなので質問だけの誤字とは思いますが。

Comment: 確かに誤記でした。コード上はandroid.support.v4.contentになっていたので、間違いはないかと思います。

Comment: 開発環境の構築がそもそもうまくできていないようですね。eclipseはもうサポートされてなかったと思いますので、やむを得ない理由がない限りAndroidStudioを利用されてください。