# SDKManagerでFetchエラーじゃないのに一覧表示されない

Tags: android, eclipse

SDKManagerを開いてもリストにはすでにインストールできているもの以外は表示されず、Logをみると、
null
Fetching URL: http://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
Done loading packages.
となってFetchエラーというわけではないのです。1行目のnullというのも気になりますがよくわかりません。これはどういうことが考えられるのでしょうか。
SDKManager以外にSupport Libraryを更新できる方法があればそちらでも構いません。
教えて頂きたいです。

Comment: 先に回答記載してしまいましたが http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/32065/getcolor%e3%81%afcontextcompat%e3%81%a7%e6%9c%aa%e5%ae%9a%e7%be%a9%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99 を見ますと「android6.0やb‌​uild toolsなどは自力で落とした」とあります。多少通常と異なる方法でセットアップを行われているようですので、その「自力で」の詳細な方法や、ご自身のネットワーク環境、SDK ManagerのVersion、SDKManagerがstand alone起動かもしくはAndroidStudioのBundle起動か。(あるいはAndroidStudioではなくEclipse？)などの情報があればより正確な回答ができるかと思います。

Comment: Proxy設定してあります。Force～というのもチェックを入れたほうが良いと見たことがあったので入れてあります。
自力での方法は、例えばhttp://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xmlのなかから必要なzipファイルを探してダウンロードするです。どこかのサイトでこのような方法を見つけてやりました。ちなみに、Eclipseをインストールした直後はSDKManagerのリストにAndroidの様々なバージョンが表示されていました。stand alone起動やEclipseからの起動どちらでも同じ状態です。SDK Managerのバージョンはr21でbuild toolsは25.0.2です。USB DriverなどはEclipseを初めにインストールした際に、SDKManagerからインストールしました。

Comment: SDK Manager(SDKTools Version25.2.5)です。Clear Cacheも試しましたが何も変わりませんでした。
https://sakapon.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/androidsdksetup/
このサイトにあるようなやり方で必要なものをインストールしました。

Comment: 問題点が二つあるように見えました。①proxy設定をしたはずだが、Add-onサイトにアクセスできない。　②①の問題があったので手動でzipを落としてきたが、目的のadd-onがinstall候補にない。　"②"及びご提示のサイトの解決方法は手動でadd-onをinstallする方法であり、add-onの入手先のrepogitoryを手動追加する方法ではないのでinstall済みのadd-onしか表示されないのは当然の結果となります。Tool>Manage add-on sitesの中に表示されているrepogitoryは何がありますでしょうか？ここが表示されていないならばproxyの設定や何かしらのnetworkの設定がうまく行っていないものと思われます。

Comment: 確かにAdd-on Siteに表示がありません。ここがないから探しようがないということなんですかね。User Defined Sitesというタブがありますが、そこに何かサイトのURLなどを追加すれば良いのでしょうか。

Comment: UserDefinedSitesを設定しても、proxyの設定がうまく行ってない以上つながらないと思います。まずはproxyの設定やその他ネットワークの設定を再度見直されたほうがよろしいかと思います。

Comment: そもそもの話になってしまいますが、eclipseは

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ご使用の環境はproxy使用環境でしょうか？
であればSDK ManagerのSystemSettings > HTTP Proxy　よりProxyの設定をおねがいします。

そうでないならば、以下で似たようなエントリがありました。
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37877
同現象かはわかりませんがCacheの削除を試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

ただ"The newer release doesn't have the bug anymore."の記載があり、
最新版のSDK Managerでは発生しないとされています。
私のSDK Manager(SDKTools Version25.2.2)上にはClear Cacheメニューがありませんでした。

Comment: <HOME>\.eclipse\org.eclipse.equinox.security\secure_storageというファイルを削除する方法でSDKManagerが正常に繋がりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 環境は認証Proxy環境下だったのでしょうか。であれば認証情報が読み込めていなかったのでしょうね。